# Call python function with Django

Tags: python, html, django, function, button

I've recently started learning how to use Django and I was wondering whether or not you could create a button in HTML that can directly call a python function without changing the URL. I was told this was possible with JS but I wanted to know if you could do that in Python.

Thanks for your time reading this!

Answer (score 1):

A potential option if you're not ready to dig deep into javascript is to look into [HTMX](https://htmx.org/).

You can just create a django view with whatever python functionality you want, and use HTMX to perform a get or post call to it. Here I'm just returning a chunk of html that will be inserted into the `dataLocation` div, but you could literally call anything that's possible with python from your view and return useful html.

index.html

```
<button hx-get="/alert_message/" hx-target="#dataLocation" hx-swap="innerHTML">
    Click Me
</button>

<div id="dataLocation"></div>
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def alert_message(request):
    return HttpResponse(
            (
                "<div class='alert alert-warning'>"
                "    <strong>Warning!</strong> Some important message."
                "</div>"
            ),
            status=200,
            content_type="text/html",
        )
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('alert_message/', views.alert_message, name='alert_message'),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application you may want to look into Django forms. Otherwise JS (ajax) is the way to go. More details could always help.

Comment: hey mate, Thanks a lot for the response! I will look into using Django forms. My issue is that I simply don't like the idea of a url change on a button click to print Hello World for example!